# Fast way to process array for waveform rendering

Tags: java, javascript, algorithm, gwt

I have this code for my web application that I need some improvement, it works somehow but the outcome is quite slow:

The idea behind this code are:

- The function gets the current buffer and then transpose it into an array (with 50ms sampling rate)
- At every sampling, the elements of the array must be rendered by passing each element in the updateWave function
- For the next iteration, the current buffer is fetched again, but it contains the previous data (so previous data/elements should not be rendered) the new elements must be rendered again.

**Updated (simplified code)**:

```
private String data = "";   
// This function renders the waveform in the page, has been tested to
// render properly and smoothly by passing random double value at 50ms interval    
public void updateWave(String waveValue){
    wave.renderWaveOnFly(Double.parseDouble(waveValue));
}

public final native void waveIt()/*-{   
    var instance = this;
    $wnd._waver = setInterval(function(){
            // Get the current buffer from the flash interface
            // Note it fetches everything in the buffer
            var newData = $wnd.Recorder.audioData().toString();
            var strData = newData.toString();
            var arr = strData.split(',');
            var arrEl = arr.pop();
            instance.@com.mycode.wavegwt.showcase.client.Showcase::updateWave(Ljava/lang/String;)(arrEl.toString());
            //console.log(arrEl);
        }
    ,50);
}-*/;

// This function renders the waveform from math function 
// and the waveform is smooth and the UI is still responsive
public final native void waveItByRandomValue()/*-{  
    var instance = this;
    $wnd._waver = setInterval(function(){
            var arrEl = Math.cos(i++/25) - 0.2 + Math.random() * 0.3;
            instance.@com.mycode.wavegwt.showcase.client.Showcase::updateWave(Ljava/lang/String;)(arrEl.toString());
        }
    ,50);
}-*/;

public native void renderWaveOnFly(Double _data)/*-{
    var data = $wnd.data;
    data.push(_data);
    $wnd._waveform.update({
        data: data
    });
}-*/;
```

`waveIt()` is a function that reads a buffer from a flash interface (which gets its data from the microphone). For the demo, I set the mic recorder to record 10 seconds when triggered, then when recording starts `waveIt()`, after 10 seconds call `clearInterval($wnd._waver)`

**The problem with this:**

- `waveIt()` function is really slow, i.e, the UI is not responsive when running this and that the rendering takes so slow
- Compared to `waveItByRandomValue()` which renders fast and the UI is still responsive when running this function

I am running out of strategy on how to make this work right.

To see my project live see this: http://bitly.com/XGboA1

I also did explain a bit more of this problem in Google Groups: http://bitly.com/SqSZVl

Comment: Could you use an interpolation algorithm to speed up wave processing. I've done this with heart rate waveforms before with success.

Comment: Are you testing in Dev Mode or with compiled JS? Dev Mode has very poor performance, doubly so when calling into JSNI, so be sure to test for performance in production mode only.

Comment: @wvxvw The flash library I use is already compiled I took from third party source. And even if I process the array in Flash, the problem would be really the speed issue with feeding the array into the waveform generator 'updateWave'

Comment: @wvxvw I mean the problem is that the data from $wnd.Recorder.audioData().toString() grows in time, and the problem is that my 'setInterval' solution is not so natural

Comment: @ColinAlworth I'm testing both in Dev Mode and in compiled JS, the compile version is this: http://bitly.com/XGboA1 although my idea is that it should at least work in Dev Mode, since pushing random values into the 'updateWave' renders smooth enough in dev mode, the real deal is to replace the random data with the real-time data I get from flash

Comment: @chrislhardin Your idea looks great, would it work with the kind of data source I have? And the way I get the data from flash? I mean I am getting all the data buffer every 50ms

Comment: @wvxvw I know the library I get the data as comma-separated floating point values

Comment: @wvxvw I know the library I get the data as comma-separated floating point values, and yes I really think the problem is with having to do split at 50ms interval

Comment: @wvxvw I know the library I get the data as comma-separated floating point values, and yes I really think the problem is with having to do split at 50ms interval

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18736/discussion-between-xybrek-and-wvxvw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a part of the solution, typed arrays :

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/